# Highmaps get() function on a secondary series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have this map with two series very much like this one: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d_paul/ym2nhfyq/)

On the load() event I'm able to zoom in to a specific element of the first series like this:

```js
this.get('TX').zoomTo();
```

That works as expected.  But I can't figure out how to zoom to an item of the second series (a bubble).  I tried the same call with the ID of a bubble and it says it is undefined.  I suppose I need somehow to specify it is in the second series, but how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mapbubble` series point has not `zoomTo` method in it's prototype, but you can add it in this way:

```
Highcharts.seriesTypes.mapbubble.prototype.pointClass.prototype.zoomTo = function() {
  var point = this,
    series = point.series;

  series.xAxis.setExtremes(point._minX, point._maxX, false);
  series.yAxis.setExtremes(point._minY, point._maxY, false);
  series.chart.redraw();
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4783/

Comment: Works nicely!  Thank you very much.